# Reading performance counters in Apple Sillicon in a Kernel Module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, perf, apple-silicon

I have a M2 apple machine with Asahi Linux running on it. I'm trying to write a kernel module and in the module I want to measure the number of cycles spent on running a set of assembly instructions. Now I know that the default ARM performance registers don't work on M1 or M2 and apple has implemented their own PMC registers.

The problem with directly reading the PMC0 register(asm eq. `MRS X0, PMC0`) is that it has to be initialized, enabled and events have to be defined via apple's performance monitor control register(PMCR0) first, which is a lot of work to include in my own module.

I have seen Asahi team's work for Perf [here](https://github.com/AsahiLinux/linux/blob/b5c05cbffb0488c7618106926d522cc3b43d93d5/drivers/perf/apple_m1_cpu_pmu.c) which works fine. I'm not sure if I could actually use Perf in my case.

So my question is, is it possible to use Perf tool to measure the cycles on some part of a kernel module? I'd also very much appreciate any other ideas.

Comment: It should be really an exceptional case when you can not use `perf` tool.

Comment: Thanks! but I actually ended up initializing and enabling counters in my own code using the codes from Asahi.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do a similar thing (read pmc in userspace on M2).
I'm able to get it accessible to userspace by writing an msr (0x40000000ull to msr s3_1_c15_c0_0) but it always counts 0.
It would be really helpful if you could share your code initializing the counter so I can check what I'm missing :)

Comment: Hi @LorenzHetterich , posted my answer. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I used already implemented code from Asahi to setup the performance counters on M1 in my own kernel module:

```
void setup_counter(int pmc_counter){
    //configure
    u64 val, user_bit, kernel_bit;
    user_bit = BIT(get_bit_offset(pmc_counter, PMCR1_COUNT_A64_EL0_0_7));
    kernel_bit = BIT(get_bit_offset(pmc_counter, PMCR1_COUNT_A64_EL1_0_7));


    val = read_sysreg_s(SYS_IMP_APL_PMCR1_EL1);
    val |= user_bit;
    val |= kernel_bit;
    write_sysreg_s(val, SYS_IMP_APL_PMCR1_EL1);
    isb();

    //enable
    write_sysreg_s(0xff, sys_reg(3, 1, 15, 0, 0));
    isb();

    //start
    val = read_sysreg_s(SYS_IMP_APL_PMCR0_EL1);
    val &= ~(PMCR0_IMODE | PMCR0_IACT);
    val |= FIELD_PREP(PMCR0_IMODE, PMCR0_IMODE_FIQ);
    write_sysreg_s(val, SYS_IMP_APL_PMCR0_EL1);
    isb();
}
```

And here's the header file:

```
#ifndef __TIMING_h
#define __TIMING_h

#include <linux/bits.h>
#include <asm/sysreg.h>

/* Counters */
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMC0_EL1    sys_reg(3, 2, 15, 0, 0)
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMC1_EL1    sys_reg(3, 2, 15, 1, 0)
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMC2_EL1    sys_reg(3, 2, 15, 2, 0)
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMC3_EL1    sys_reg(3, 2, 15, 3, 0)
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMC4_EL1    sys_reg(3, 2, 15, 4, 0)
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMC5_EL1    sys_reg(3, 2, 15, 5, 0)
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMC6_EL1    sys_reg(3, 2, 15, 6, 0)
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMC7_EL1    sys_reg(3, 2, 15, 7, 0)
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMC8_EL1    sys_reg(3, 2, 15, 9, 0)
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMC9_EL1    sys_reg(3, 2, 15, 10, 0)

/* Core PMC control register */
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMCR0_EL1   sys_reg(3, 1, 15, 0, 0)
#define PMCR0_CNT_ENABLE_0_7    GENMASK(7, 0)
#define PMCR0_IMODE     GENMASK(10, 8)
#define PMCR0_IMODE_OFF     0
#define PMCR0_IMODE_PMI     1
#define PMCR0_IMODE_AIC     2
#define PMCR0_IMODE_HALT    3
#define PMCR0_IMODE_FIQ     4
#define PMCR0_IACT      BIT(11)
#define PMCR0_PMI_ENABLE_0_7    GENMASK(19, 12)
#define PMCR0_STOP_CNT_ON_PMI   BIT(20)
#define PMCR0_CNT_GLOB_L2C_EVT  BIT(21)
#define PMCR0_DEFER_PMI_TO_ERET BIT(22)
#define PMCR0_ALLOW_CNT_EN_EL0  BIT(30)
#define PMCR0_CNT_ENABLE_8_9    GENMASK(33, 32)
#define PMCR0_PMI_ENABLE_8_9    GENMASK(45, 44)

#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMCR1_EL1   sys_reg(3, 1, 15, 1, 0)
#define PMCR1_COUNT_A64_EL0_0_7 GENMASK(15, 8)
#define PMCR1_COUNT_A64_EL1_0_7 GENMASK(23, 16)
#define PMCR1_COUNT_A64_EL0_8_9 GENMASK(41, 40)
#define PMCR1_COUNT_A64_EL1_8_9 GENMASK(49, 48)

#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMCR2_EL1   sys_reg(3, 1, 15, 2, 0)
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMCR3_EL1   sys_reg(3, 1, 15, 3, 0)
#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMCR4_EL1   sys_reg(3, 1, 15, 4, 0)

#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMESR0_EL1  sys_reg(3, 1, 15, 5, 0)
#define PMESR0_EVT_CNT_2    GENMASK(7, 0)
#define PMESR0_EVT_CNT_3    GENMASK(15, 8)
#define PMESR0_EVT_CNT_4    GENMASK(23, 16)
#define PMESR0_EVT_CNT_5    GENMASK(31, 24)

#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMESR1_EL1  sys_reg(3, 1, 15, 6, 0)
#define PMESR1_EVT_CNT_6    GENMASK(7, 0)
#define PMESR1_EVT_CNT_7    GENMASK(15, 8)
#define PMESR1_EVT_CNT_8    GENMASK(23, 16)
#define PMESR1_EVT_CNT_9    GENMASK(31, 24)

#define SYS_IMP_APL_PMSR_EL1    sys_reg(3, 1, 15, 13, 0)
#define PMSR_OVERFLOW       GENMASK(9, 0)

#define get_bit_offset(index, mask) (__ffs(mask) + (index))

extern void setup_counter(int pmc_counter);
#define read_clk_counter() read_sysreg_s(SYS_IMP_APL_PMC0_EL1);
#define read_instruction_counter() read_sysreg_s(SYS_IMP_APL_PMC1_EL1);

#endif /* __TIMING_h */
```